# DialogFlow PermissionDenied: 403 IAM permission 'dialogflow.sessions.detectIntent'

Tags: dialogflow-es

PermissionDenied: 403 IAM permission 'dialogflow.sessions.detectIntent' on 'projects/XXXX-live/agent' denied.

I have used the DialogFlow client as a role while creating the service.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 8):

When I was playing around with permissions with service accounts, I also encountered the same problem. I created a completely new service account and then gave it the client role, and it worked for some unknown reason. 
I would suggest trying to create another account and then giving it the client role and seeing if it works for that account.
Also, this isn't necessarily a kosher fix per say, but if you give the account the admin role, then your problem will also be solved.

Edit: At first I thought it might have to do with how the service accounts were created (cloud console vs. command-line), but it seems that's not the case. For some reason it's just the first service account that you create that a client role doesn't work for.

Comment: This fixed it for me: the first account doesn't work, second one does.

Comment: Oh my goodness, creating a new service account helped, finally! :) Thanks LiminalKryosis.

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue while integrating Dialogflow with external client.

The root cause for my case was that even though I created the service account for my external client, I forgot to add the service account and give "Dialogflow API Admin' Role.

How I resolve: In GCP project, go to IAM > click the top "+ADD" button and search for the service account that you want to grant permission access, choose role type "Dialogflow API Admin"

Comment: I have created new service account, and in optional section grant this service account access to project by Selecting role DialogFlow API Admin and client. And then created new key as json file. then paste this json file into the android project raw folder. Its works for me.

Comment: Worked well for a new dialogflow instace

Answer (score 0):

I solved my error by doing this

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    'C:\\Users\\ashis\\Downloads\\id.json')
def create_intent(project_id, display_name, training_phrases_parts,
                  message_texts):
    """Create an intent of the given intent type."""
    intents_client = dialogflow.IntentsClient(credentials=credentials)
    # session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient(credentials=credentials)
```

Then I went to the IAM settings for my project
https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project=
and gave the dialogflow service account members a higher role(like project owner).

Answer (score 0):

You have to give permission to the mega agent.

Answer (score 0):

THE SOLUTION IS VERY EASY -> **SELECT PARENT PROJECT WHILE CREATING AGENT. DON'T CREATE NEW PROJECT. BECAUSE IT WON'T INHERIT THE JSON KEY PERMISSIONS**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmnwa.jpg)

This solved my issue. I hope you'll find it useful. I tried this with several projects and found this working perfectly. Happy coding!

```py
#importing dialogflow
from google.cloud import dialogflow_v2beta1 as df1 

#declaring contsant values
DF_PROJ_ID = "xxxxx"
DF_LANG_CODE = "en"
SESSION_ID = "me"
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'xxxxxxx.json'

#define dialogflow
def DF (text_to_be_analyzed): 
    global agent_reply, conf, answer
    session_client = df1.SessionsClient()
    session = session_client.session_path(DF_PROJ_ID, SESSION_ID)
    text_input= df1.types.TextInput(text=text_to_be_analyzed, language_code=DF_LANG_CODE)
    query_input = df1.types.QueryInput (text=text_input)
    try:
        response = session_client.detect_intent (session=session, query_input=query_input)
        print("Query text:", response.query_result.query_text)
        agent_reply = response.query_result.intent.display_name
        conf = response.query_result.intent_detection_confidence
        print(" Detected intent is: " + agent_reply + " | Detected intent confidence:", conf , end="|")
        answer= response.query_result. fulfillment_text
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception: " + str(e))
        answer= 'nu'
        agent_reply = 'error'
        print ("Dialogflow Connection Error ", end="")
        pass
    if answer != 'nu':
        print(answer)
    return agent_reply

#call dialogflow
DF(query)
```