# Google cloud dialogflow intent detection nodejs example not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I am trying to implement a very simple dialogflow agent integration with nodejs.

Here is what I did so far

- I followed the code from [Intent detection](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/detect-intent-text)
- I added the service account private key file `.json` to my server.
- I added the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` with the path to my `.json` private key file.

Here is the code I am trying to run right now:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const projectId = 'gg-chatbot-216808'; 
const sessionId = 'quickstart-session-id';
const query = 'hello';
const languageCode = 'en-US';

// Instantiate a DialogFlow client.
const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient();

// Define session path
const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);

// The text query request.
const request = {
    session: sessionPath,
    queryInput: {
        text: {
            text: query,
            languageCode: languageCode,
        },
    },
};

// This prints the private key path correctly.
console.log(process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS);

// Send request and log result
sessionClient
    .detectIntent(request)
    .then(responses => {
        console.log('Detected intent');
        const result = responses[0].queryResult;
        console.log(`  Query: ${result.queryText}`);
        console.log(`  Response: ${result.fulfillmentText}`);
        if (result.intent) {
            console.log(`  Intent: ${result.intent.displayName}`);
        } else {
            console.log(`  No intent matched.`);
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('ERROR:', err);
    });
```

Then I get this error in the console when I run this file

```
Auth error:Error: invalid_user: Robot is disabled.
ERROR: { Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: invalid_user: Robot is disabled.
    at Object.exports.createStatusError (/var/www/html/google_auth/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:87:15)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/var/www/html/google_auth/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1188:28)
    at InterceptingListener._callNext (/var/www/html/google_auth/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:564:42)
    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/var/www/html/google_auth/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:614:8)
    at callback (/var/www/html/google_auth/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:841:24)
  code: 14,
  metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} },
  details: 'Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: invalid_user: Robot is disabled.' }
```

Comment: are you developing a webhook for the agent? in that case try to use the following NodeJS client https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs

Comment: this libraray might help, https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow-helper I wrote this library on the top of dialogflow rest client

Answer (score 0):

i also faced a similar issue for my angular bot.

What i did was, instead of using using the google_credentials from the json file, i created an object with **private_key,client_email** {these values can be taken from the service account private key file .json}, and passed the object while setting up the session client.

```
var config = {
  credentials: {
    private_key: "YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY",
    client_email: "YOUR_CLIENT_EMAIL"
  }
}

const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient(config);
```

**note**: do copy the full private_key string from .json. It will start as `"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n......"` .

Also, in GCP go to the project->IAM then try setting role for the service as DIALOGLOW API ADMIN. Check if this works.

Comment: this libraray might help, https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow-helper I wrote this library on the top of dialogflow rest client

Answer (score 0):

If this has not been resolved yet , the solution is to provide "fileKey" inside sessionClient.

```
const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({
fileKey:" path of your credentials.json file"
});
```

or

```
let filePath = process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS ="Location of credentials file".

const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({
fileKey:filePath
});
```

this will even work if there is no system env variable is set as GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.

Hope this is helpful.