# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Google\ApiCore\ApiException:

Tags: php, dialogflow-es

I am fetching my agent details from dialogflow using php client API

I have authenticated my agent on google clous sdk.Moreover,other methods work perfectly fine.

```php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Dialogflow\V2\AgentsClient;
use Google\Cloud\Dialogflow\V2\SessionsClient;
function get_agent($projectId,$sessionId,$project_name)
{
    $test = array('credentials' => 'client-secret.json');
    $sessionsClient = new SessionsClient($test);
    $session = $sessionsClient->sessionName($projectId, $sessionId ?: 
    uniqid());
    printf('Session path: %s' . PHP_EOL, $session);
    $agentsClient = new AgentsClient();
    try{
        $formattedParent = $agentsClient->projectName($project_name);
        $response = $agentsClient->getAgent($formattedParent);
    } 
    finally {
        $agentsClient->close();
    }
}
get_agent('xxxx-faqs-kcdeuh','1234','xxxx');
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google\ApiCore\ApiException: 
>   { "message": "IAM permission 'dialogflow.agents.get' on 'projects/xxxxx' denied.",
>   "code": 7,
>   "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",}

Comment: Use the catch part of your try block to catch the exception `try { ... } catch(Exception $e) { ... } finally { ...}`

Comment: @Qirel i didnt get you..can you please eloborate?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is an `IAM permission denied`, which means that you are authenticated, but not authorized to perform a `'dialogflow.agents.get'` action on the `'projects/xxxx'` object.

To be able to overcome this impediment, an administrator of the resource (projects/xxxxxx) needs to grant the required permission (dialogflow.agents.get).

Here is an answer explaining the process: [PermissionDenied: 403 IAM permission 'dialogflow.intents.list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52332247/permissiondenied-403-iam-permission-dialogflow-intents-list)

Comment: yes,exactly but how do i solve this issue in order to get agent information.

Comment: that solution will NOT work *as is*, did you change the permission to "dialogflow.agents.get" ?

Comment: Sorry, actually i didnt get you...which one to be followed and where to change permission to **dialogflow.agents.get**