# 403 IAM permission despite giving admin permissions to the agent to give permissions to list intent

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, permissions, dialogflow-es

I want to use the chatbot I created with Dialogflow as the main page of my website. Yet it tells me that `google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 IAM permission 'dialogflow.sessions.detectIntent' on 'projects/pollingagent-jnscpa/agent' denied.`
when trying to talk to him.

I followed [this tutorial](https://pusher.com/tutorials/chatbot-flask-dialogflow) that tells how to do it with Flask but I'm ready to shift to the easiest solution.
I tried the following thing from the answers to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52332247/permissiondenied-403-iam-permission-dialogflow-intents-list):

- In Dialogflow's console, going to settings ⚙ > under the general tab, there is the project ID section with a Google Cloud link to open the Google Cloud console > Open Google Cloud.
- In google cloud, going to IAM Admin > IAM under tab Members. Find the name of my agents and then click on edit.
- Give admin permissions to the agent to give permissions to list intent.

[image]

So I don't know, maybe the problem is from my index.py?

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import os
import dialogflow

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def detect_intent_texts(project_id, session_id, text, language_code):
    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()
    session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)

    if text:
        text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(
            text=text, language_code=language_code)
        query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)
        response = session_client.detect_intent(
            session=session, query_input=query_input)

        return response.query_result.fulfillment_text

@app.route('/send_message', methods=['POST'])
def send_message():
    message = request.form['message']
    project_id = os.getenv('DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID')
    fulfillment_text = detect_intent_texts(project_id, "unique", message, 'en')
    response_text = { "message":  fulfillment_text }

    return jsonify(response_text)

# run Flask app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't setup the credentials in the code, do you have the environment variable set for credentials?

The `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` variable is the easiest way to do this, where the value of that variable is set to the path to the service account key that you download.

You can do this in the code as well if you want, so it doesn't affect the rest of your environment with something like:

`os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = 'path/to/private_key.json'`

Comment: yes, I did it in my `.env` file: `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=privatekey*.json`

Comment: Like they do in the tutorial

Comment: Ah gotcha. It COULD be that you're not loading the dotenv file (which the tutorial kind of glosses over because Flask under certain startup situations loads it for you). JUUUUST as a test, try adding ```from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv('.env') #the path to your .env file (or any other file of environment variable``` to your code.

Comment: Or alternately, just do a `print(os.environ('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'))` to be sure it's set.

Answer (score 2):

There can be one of the two issues which you might be facing:

1. You might not have set the path to json credential file properly. You can either set it as an environment variable or do `os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']="/path/to/project_name-xxxxxxxx.json"`
2. Goto dialogflow homepage and then click on the displayed location [image]

Then click on PROJECT_ID link to goto your google cloud console

After you are in google cloud console, open the side menu panel as displayed and then goto IAM & Admin > IAM

[image]

You should see all the members and if the role is not set to Owner then click on edit icon and change role to owner

[image]

With the following steps I was able to run my the following snippet

```
from google.cloud import dialogflow 
import random 
import string 
import os

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = "\path\to\<project_name>-xxxxxx.json"

x = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(16))

client_session = dialogflow.SessionsClient()

session = client_session.session_path("<project_name>", x)

print(session)

text = input("Please enter a text : ")

text_input = dialogflow.TextInput(text=text, language_code='en') 
query_input = dialogflow.QueryInput(text=text_input) 
response = client_session.detect_intent(
        request={'session': session, 'query_input': query_input}) 
print('=' * 20) 
print('Query text: {}'.format(response.query_result.query_text)) 
print('Detected intent: {} (confidence: {})\n'.format(
            response.query_result.intent.display_name,
            response.query_result.intent_detection_confidence)) 
print('Fulfillment text: {}\n'.format(response.query_result.fulfillment_text))
```